# UIScrollView dragging overrules subview touchesBegan

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, touchesbegan

All,

I have read a lot of answers on stackoverflow and other sites and tried a lot of possible solutions, but none work.

I have a UIScrollView (boardScrollView) with a subview which is the backgroundimage (boardImage):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyblue_numbered_15x15_900x900.png"];
self.boardImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.boardImage.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};
[self.boardScrollView addSubview:self.boardImage];
self.boardScrollView.contentSize = image.size;
```

I have implemented the touchesBegan and touchesEnded to drag&drop another subview around on the UIScrollView:

```
- (void)myTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPointScreen = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint touchPointImage  = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.boardImage];

 if (touchPointScreen.x > self.boardScrollView.frame.origin.x &&
     touchPointScreen.x < self.boardScrollView.frame.origin.x + self.boardScrollView.frame.size.width &&
     touchPointScreen.y > self.boardScrollView.frame.origin.y &&
     touchPointScreen.y < self.boardScrollView.frame.origin.y + self.boardScrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        self.tmpDragObject.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,60,60);

        [self.boardImage addSubview:self.tmpDragObject];
    }
  self.tmpDragObject = nil;
}
```

The dragged subview is dropped on the imageview. I can zoom in and out and the subview is also repositioned.

This works perfect when the scrollview is zoomed out. When I make a drag-motion, the subview is dragged on the scrollview.

But when I zoom in on the scrollview and then try to drag the dropped subview, the touchesBegan is overruled by the scrollViewWillBeginDragging method, so the scrollview is scrolled, but the subview is not dragged..
Somehow, the dragging overrules the touchesBegan method. 
Because when I only touch, the subview's touchesBegan method is called. But when I make a drag-motion, the dragging-method from the UIScrollView is called.

How can I make both the dragging in the scrollview and the touchesBegan in the subview to work when I drag the scrollview from the position of the subview?

I have set the

```
self.boardScrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
self.boardScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

and on the subview

```
self.exclusiveTouch = YES;
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

What am I missing here?